# videojs plugins shows multiple times on control bar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video.js

I had to display a video on my Angular website and I have used videojs player for displaying. Video has multiple bit rate selector, so I used videojs-hls-quality-selector plugin and for seek bar, I have used videojs-seek-buttons. everything works properly on desktop but when I open player on mobile it shows 2 time seek bar and 2 times quality selector in the control bar.

Below is the code I have used

TypeScript code:

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'videojs-seek-buttons';
import 'videojs-contrib-quality-levels';
import videojsqualityselector from 'videojs-hls-quality-selector';


videoJSPlayer: videojs.Player;

this.videoJSPlayer = videojs('content_video', {
      aspectRatio: '16:9',
      fluid: true,
      controlBar: {
        'pictureInPictureToggle': false
      },
      html5: {
        hls: {
          overrideNative: true,
        }
      },
      sources: [{
        src: this.vSource,
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
      }],
      poster: this.vThumb
});

this.videoJSPlayer.seekButtons({
      forward: 30,
      back: 10
});

this.videoJSPlayer.hlsQualitySelector = videojsqualityselector;
this.videoJSPlayer.hlsQualitySelector({
      displayCurrentQuality: true,
});
```

HTML code:

```
<video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none"
        data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]}'>
</video>
```

I have attached screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the issue, but I'd imagine this is because by default, video.js will automatically initialize any `video` element with a `data-setup` parameter.

> By default, when your web page finishes loading, Video.js will scan for media elements that have the data-setup attribute. The data-setup attribute is used to pass options to Video.js. https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html

I'm guessing that the seek buttons plugin hooks into some event that occurs when the video player is initialized, and adds the buttons.  Because you then initialize it in code, they get added twice.  Most likely you just need to remove the `data-setup` attribute, and move any of the configuration that you want to keep into javascript.